# Problems with tasks and max execution time

Tags: tasks

We've set up a task that's supposed to run through an external folder with images and resize them into 3 sizes each. This results in about 13000 tasks (one task per image). I thought each task was on a separate thread? But now the tasks are running for only 60 seconds (max_execution_time), then stopping. The task says `running` in the database, but it has just stopped, and the error log says max execution time was exceeded.

Is there a way around this? Would sub tasks change any behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Tasks are just another PHP request and they are subject to the same web server and `php.ini` limitations as a "normal" request.

Sounds like you just need to up your [max_execution_time](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

Comment: But are all the tasks run as _one_ request? Or are they split up into separate requests? Because each task takes less than a second to complete, but we're getting maxed out after 30 seconds of running tasks. It usually completes around 80-100 tasks before shutting down.

Comment: Yes - a task is run as one request even if it has multiple sub-tasks.